# How to handle multiple "valid after {date}" in a performant way

Tags: c#, design-patterns, database-design, sql, stored-procedures

We work on an Application which displays a duty roster and also some other DateTime related things.

So my Database is full of Relations like in this small Example:

[image: Simple Example Database]

This results in big StoredProcedure to get all Employee Data and it's Date related Data for a given Employee and Day, Month ,Year combination

which looks like this (based on the Example):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Mitarbeiter_Select

    @myDate         AS datetime2(7) = null, -- null represent current
    @EmployeeId     AS int          = null  -- null represents all Employees

AS
    -- declare my intern parameters
    DECLARE @oldDate                AS datetime2(7)= null;  

    SET @Wann   = ISNULL(@Wann,GETDATE());

    -- set the previous month
    SET @oldDate= DATEADD(month, -1, @Wann); -- for some calculations i need information from the month before


    --############################# REGION TEMP TABLE ###########################
    -- create my TempTable
    create table #EmployeeToFind
    (
        ID int, 
        FirstName nvarchar(MAX), 
        LastName nvarchar(MAX)        
    )

    create table #EmployeeVacationDays
    (
        RefEmployeeId int, 
        YearDays int
    )

    create table #EmployeeManager
    (
        RefEmployeeId int, 
        IsManager bit
    )


    --############################# REGION FILL TABLE ###########################

    INSERT INTO #EmployeeToFind
    SELECT  ID, 
            Personalnummer, 
            FirstName , 
            LastName 
    FROM    Employee
    WHERE   ID = ISNULL(@EmployeeId, ID)

    INSERT INTO #EmployeeVacationDays
    SELECT  RefEmployeeId , 
            Days AS YearDays 
    FROM    VacationDays OUTERMU
    WHERE   RefEmployeeId = ISNULL(@EmployeeId, RefEmployeeId )
    AND     ValidAfter =    (
                                    SELECT  MAX(ValidAfter )
                                    FROM    VacationDays
                                    WHERE   RefEmployeeId = OUTERMU.RefEmployeeId 
                                    AND     (   YEAR(ValidAfter) = YEAR(@Wann) 
                                                OR      
                                                YEAR(ValidAfter) < YEAR(@Wann)
                                            )
                            )

    INSERT INTO #EmployeeManager
    SELECT  RefEmployeeId , 
            IsManager 
    FROM    Manager
    WHERE   RefEmployeeId = ISNULL(@EmployeeId, RefEmployeeId )
    AND     ValidAfter =    (
                                    SELECT  MAX(ValidAfter )
                                    FROM    Manager
                                    WHERE   RefEmployeeId = OUTERMA.RefEmployeeId 
                                    AND     (   YEAR(ValidAfter) = YEAR(@Wann) AND  MONTH(ValidAfter)  <= MONTH(@Wann)
                                                OR      
                                                YEAR(ValidAfter) < YEAR(@Wann)
                                            )
                            )


    --############################# REGION RESULT SELECT ###########################
    SELECT  #EmployeeToFind.ID, 
            #EmployeeToFind.FirstName , 
            #EmployeeToFind.LastName , 
            #EmployeeVacationDays.YearDays ,
            #EmployeeManager.IsManager ,

    -- in our real Procedure we have here also some CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END
    -- Depending on IS NULL/ IS NOT NULL of some Values

    FROM #EmployeeToFind
    left outer join #EmployeeVacationDayson #EmployeeToFind.ID= #EmployeeVacationDays.RefEmployeeId 
    left outer join #EmployeeManageron #EmployeeToFind.ID= #EmployeeManager.RefEmployeeId
```

Now my Question is there a way to simplify this?

Comment: What exactly do you want to simplify? `SELECT` query?

Comment: @VladislavRastrusny everything that's possible, so if you are able to make a simple query which is also easy to read or you are able to provide a other way of data normalization so we could create a simpler i would really appreciate any of your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

The question mentions performance, but in the body you ask about simplifying.

The most important things I've done that dramatically improved our worst performing procedures:

1. Indexes on the join columns
2. Indexes as needed without consideration of index maintenance overhead.
3. Ensure column order in compound indexes was in the order as used in where or join.
4. Ensure we had indexes on foreign keys
5. Made temp tables permanent tables and created indexes.
6. Truncate rather than delete when clearing the (now permanent) temp tables.
7. Rebuild statistics immediately after filling tables.
8. The above was not pure guess work. Our DBA analyzed logs on how, if, where existing indexes were used and he made suggestions where new indexes might help.